# How to pass a class name to a function and init var with class name inside the function

Tags: swift, generics

In Swift 4, I would like to pass a class name to a function :

```
let usingClass = MyClass.self
myFuntion(usingClass)
```

My function :

```
func myFuntion <T>(_ typeClass: T.Type) {
...
var myVar: [typeClass]
...

}
```

When I compile, I obtain the following error message :

> Used of undeclared type 'typeClass'

on the line `var myVar: [typeClass]`

What am I wrong ?

Comment: You can't do that. All types need to be known at compile time, so you cannot specify the type of `myVar` in runtime.

Comment: You probably meant for it to be of type `[T]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Hamish, the answer for my issue is simply using T when I want to declare my var. With that, I can use the same function with different type and all work fine :

```
let usingClass = MyClass.self
myFuntion(usingClass)

let usingAnotherClass = MyOhterClass
myfunction(usingAnotherClass)

func myFuntion<T>(_ typeClass: T.Type) {
    ...
    var myVar: [T]
    ...
}
```